# 5x5 differential equation system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following differential system
$$\begin{pmatrix}x_1' \\ x_2' \\ x_3' \\ x_4' \\ x_5' \end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ -2 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 4 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\ -1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 3 \end{pmatrix}
\cdot \begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4 \\ x_5 \end{pmatrix}. $$
**My solution :** 
The eigenvalues are $3$ and $2$.

The eigenvectors of $3$ are :
$$v_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} , \quad v_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$

The eigenvalues of $2$ is :
$$v_3 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Therefore, the solution I found is
$$\begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4 \\ x_5 \end{pmatrix} = c_1 e^{3t}\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + c_2 e^{3t} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} + c_3 e^{2t}\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$

But when I checked the solution in wolfram it gave me a totally different solution. So my question is, what did I do wrong?

Comment: You need to compute the generalized eigenvalues as well in order to get the complete solution. Yours is correct, but is missing $2$ linearly independent terms. The answer to the following question might be of help
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364981/solving-linear-system-of-differential-equations-of-2nd-order?rq=1

Comment: So I need 5 linearly independent eigenvectors to get the general solution, right?.
Do these generalised eigenvectors corressponds to the eigenvalue 3 (or they may correspond to 2)?.
I should compute them using $(A-3I)v_4=v_1$ and $(A-3I)v_5=v_2$, right?

Comment: That would give you $v_4=v_5$, which wouldn't be of much help. Try $(A-3I)v_5=v_4$. You can verify your missing generalized eigenvectors with [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eigensystem+%7B%7B1,1,1,1,1%7D,%7B-2,4,0,2,1%7D,%7B0,0,4,-1,0%7D,%7B0,0,1,2,0%7D,%7B-1,1,0,1,3%7D%7D)

Comment: Eigenvalue 2 has order 1 and eigenvalue 3 has order 4.

Comment: One can write the general solution, using the matrix exponential, without doing any computation: $$\vec v = e^{tA}\; \vec v_0 $$ where $A$ is the $5\times 5$ matrix of coeffients and $v_0$ is the initial condition at time $t=0$.